# capture screen shot of full content of web view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new in `iOS`. I want to capture screen shot of full content of web view, as `webview` may have webpage longer that could be scrollable and so not showing the full content in length more than screen size. I am using below code like:-

```
UIImage *screenImage=[[UIImage alloc] init];
UIScrollView *browserScrollableView=[[UIScrollView alloc] init];
browserScrollableView=browserView.scrollView;   
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(browserScrollableView.contentSize);
CGPoint savedContentOffset = browserScrollableView.contentOffset;
CGRect savedFrame = browserScrollableView.frame;
browserScrollableView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
browserScrollableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, browserScrollableView.contentSize.width, browserScrollableView.contentSize.height);
[browserScrollableView.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];     
screenImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
browserScrollableView.contentOffset = savedContentOffset;
browserScrollableView.frame = savedFrame;
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSLog(@"Captured image size is %f X %f",screenImage.size.width,screenImage.size.height);
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

`browserview` is the `webview`. It's working on simulator why is it not working on device?

Comment: don't just pass `nil` `nil` `nil` to `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` use those parameters and pass the completion selector and check the error there. [Here is the reference doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum)

Comment: Thanks @Inder Kumar Rathore!!